# Vars.get returns a null value

Tags: groovy, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-5.0, jsr223

```
def signValue = '${signature_value}.${timestamp}.${signature_value}'
def token_secret = '${APP_CLIENT_SECRET}'
log.info("token is " + signValue)
def signingKey = new javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec(signValue.getBytes(),"HmacSHA256");
def mac = javax.crypto.Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256")
mac.init(signingKey);
def hmac = mac.doFinal(token_secret.getBytes());
def result = hmac.encodeBase64().toString()
---- I want to use the above "result" variable into a Http sampler request body------
---- I tried many possible ways but I end up is getting value as null or some error--
//${__groovy(vars.get("result"))}
//vars.put("signature", vars.get(result))
```

I've been trying to extract the value of the variable "result" and use it in HTTP sampler results. But I ended up getting a null value or some other error. Anyone could help me to sort out this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
vars.put("signature", vars.get(result))
```

to this:

```
vars.put("signature", result)
```

Also don't inline JMeter variables into Groovy scripts like this:

```
def token_secret = '${APP_CLIENT_SECRET}'
```

use `vars` shorthand instead:

```
def token_secret = vars.get('APP_CLIENT_SECRET')
```

Because:

- It conflicts with [Groovy GStrings](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_gstring_and_string_hashcodes)
- For best performance it's recommended to cache compiled scripts (enabled by default)

  [image]

  and in this mode JMeter resolves only first value and caches it which means you will get the same value for every iteration

More information:

- [JSR223 Sampler Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Ok, will use token_secret as said. But how could I concatenate the below,                                                                 


```
def signValue = '${signature_value}.${timestamp}.${signature_value}'
```

if I use vars.get( ) I get error. Also, how can get the length of the variable's value.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to use double quotes to get the variables evaluated. `def signValue = "${signature}.${__time()}.${signature}"`. Please check how interpolation works in Groovy for details [4.4.1. String interpolation](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation)

Comment: You can call the Groovy length() function to get the length of a variable's value. `def lengthOfVar = signValue.length()`

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the point, `result` should be a `String` object, is it not what you are expecting to have?
Anyway, `signValue` and `token_secret` perhaps could be different from your expectations: using single quotes instead of double quotes you are not using `GStrings` (e.g. the value of `token_secret` will be always exactly `'${APP_CLIENT_SECRET}'`, regardless of the value of `APP_CLIENT_SECRET`)

Answer (score 0):

Put `vars` the result:

```
 vars.put("signature", hmac.encodeBase64().toString());
```

And in HTTP use `${signature}`